# System.Web.HttpContext.Session is null with SystemWebAdapters v1.3.0 on .NET 8 yarp incremental upgrade

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-8.0, ms-yarp

I tried an example but seems .net8 and yarp 1.3 is not working together or there is a bug in VS2022. I always get the session values null in ASP.NET Core app. But downgrading to all packages of system web adaptors to 1.2 works seamlessly.

Please advise what the issue could be. Please find the repos links with ver 1.3

https://github.com/erpardeepkaushik/TestWebCore

https://github.com/erpardeepkaushik/TestWeb

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Upgraded what, from which version to which version? Why is `SystemWebAdapters` used at all? .NET 8 is .NET *Core* 8 and ASP.NET Core is very different from .NET Framework's ASP.NET. SystemWebAdapters isn't needed nor does it add functionality to ASP.NET Core projects, it only exists to allow old ASP.NET projects to be gradually migrated. There's no session storage out of the box [unless you explicitly enable it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-8.0#configure-session-state)

Answer (score 0):

i was having the same issue
so what i did is simply downgraded to framworkservices  from 1.3 to 1.1.0
also downgrade coreservices as well
then i got session value

Answer (score -1):

The issue you're encountering with `System.Web.HttpContext.Session` being null with `SystemWebAdapters` v1.3.0 on `.NET 8` might be due to a *compatibility or configuration* problem. Ensure you've correctly c*onfigured sessions and dependencies* for `.NET 8`, as the problem might stem from the upgrade or settings within your codebase.